# How to calculate the "sliding sliced" fold of an array of int arrays in F#?

Tags: arrays, f#, slice, fold, accumulator

I have a function called `calcArr_ArrOfArr` in F# with the signature `int [] -> int [][] -> int`, i.e. `calcArr_ArrOfArr` takes two arguments, an int array and an array of int arrays, and returns an int.

I want to create the function `calcArrOfArr` with the signature `int [][] -> int`, which does the following:

```
let calcArrOfArr (arrOfArr : int [][]) =
    Array.fold (fun acc e -> acc + (calcArr_ArrOfArr e arrOfArr.[?..])) 0 arrOfArr
```

where `?` would be the index of `e` + 1.
In other words, in `calcArrOfArr` I want to apply `calcArr_ArrOfArr` to every element `e` of `arrOfArr` plus the "remaining portion" of `arrOfArr`, i.e. the slice of `arrOfArr` starting from after element `e`. Of course, for the last element of `arrOfArr`, nothing would be added to the accumulator, nor would an exception be thrown.
Is there a way to create `calcArrOfArr` in a functional way? An `Array.foldi` function would come handy...

Comment: [ExtCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtCore/) includes the `Array.foldi` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you feel you need Array.foldi, write one! The following snippet will extend the built-in Array module with a foldi:

```
module Array =
    let foldi f z a = 
        a |> Array.fold (fun (i,a) x -> i+1, f i a x) (0,z) |> snd
```

Slicing from past-the-end gives you the empty array (i.e., `[|0;1|].[2..] = [||]`), so now your original suggestion works:

```
let calcArrOfArr (arrOfArr : int [][]) = 
    Array.foldi (fun i acc e -> acc + (calcArr_ArrOfArr e arrOfArr.[i+1..])) 0 arrOfArr
```

However, the slice `arrOfArr.[i+1..]` *copies* the array slice; this might be unfortunate for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't tested it, but this seems about right:

```
let calcArrOfArr (arrOfArr : int [][]) =
  arrOfArr
  |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i, x)
  |> Seq.fold (fun acc (i, e) -> acc + (calcArr_ArrOfArr e arrOfArr.[i+1..])) 0
```